# Ubuntu 14.10 built in Browser

Tags: browser

I have started to use the inbuilt light weight browser that comes with the Ubuntu 14.10 install. It is OK for what I need, however there are a few issues that I an trying to clean up with it:

1. When I scroll down the screen, after about a page length, the top bar goes and I cannot click the back arrow. I can get it back, by scrolling back up, but on a big page, that is a pain. It is like there is an auto hide of the address and navigation bar. How can I stop this from happening?
2. When I click to open a new tab, the current page I am is closed and the new tab is opened. I would of thought that the new tab function would of worked like the one in Firefox. Have I got the incorrect understanding of this?

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a built-in browser. There are one or more pre-installed browser. Which browser do you mean?

Comment: I didn't install it and when I enter browser in the search bar, it comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the mouse pointer at the very bottom of the window and the toolbar returns. Here you can use the forward and back buttons and enter a new web address.

There aren't tabs (strictly-speaking) in this browser. To access a new browser page you must open the toolbar as above and click the "Activity" button. On the subsequent screen you can see the pages that you have currently open. Click to display a page or long-click to be shown a close button to close unwanted pages.